# Iterating over dictionay inside dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I am try to iterate over a dictionary `Dictionary<uint,Dictionary<uint,uint>> myDict`.

I want to change value of internal dictionary.

When I use:

```
foreach(var item in myDict)
{
    foreach(var rt in item)
```

I get the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'KeyValuePair<uint, Dictionary<uint, uint>>' because
>   'KeyValuePair<uint, Dictionary<uint, uint>>' does not contain a public
>   instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'   SparrowView

Why can't I enumerate inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a particular key in the inner dictionary it might make more sense to you to look through the keys collection and address your dictionaries by key:

```
foreach(var outerKey in myDict.Keys)
{
   foreach(var innerKey in myDict[outerKey].Keys)
   {
     if(innerKey == 3)
       ...
   }
}
```

Alternatively, if you iterate a dictionary directly you get a keyvaluepair, so you have to keep straight in your mind the difference between a key (uint) and a value (a dictionary in your outer, a uint in your inner)

```
foreach(var outerKvp in myDict) //foreaching the outer dictionary gives a keyvaluepair, the value of which is a dictionary
{
   foreach(var innerKvp in outerKvp.Value) //outerKvp.Value is a Dictionary<uint,uint), foreaching it will again give you a keyvaluepair, this time for the inner dictionary. the value this time is a uint
   {
     if(innerKvp.Key == 3)
       ...
   }
}
```

Also bear in mind if you're looking to modify either of these you can't do it inside a for loop because you can't modify a dictionary you're enumerating over. In such cases it might be better to just use ContainsKey:

```
//for example if you know the outer key
if(myDict.ContainsKey(1) && myDict[1].ContainsKey(3))
    myDict[1][3] = 4;

//or if you don't know the outer key
foreach(var outerKey in myDict.Keys)
{
   if(myDict[outerKey].ContainsKey(3))
       myDict[outerKey][3] = 4; //this will succeed because we aren't enumerating the inner dict
}
```

Consider carefully whether this is the best data storage container for your needs; it's slightly convoluted to have a dictionary of dictionaries and you might do better making a compound key out of your uints and using a single dictionary or picking on another data storage container all together

Answer (score 5):

Please try using `item.Value`.

As you are currently iterating over both uints and the dictionary, not only the dictionary.

Comment: `item`is a KeyValuePair. KeyValuePair doesn't have a `.Values` property. Did you mean `.Value` (the inner dictionary itself) or `.Value.Values` (the values of the inner dictionary)?

Answer (score 4):

The way you using `foreach` in very iteration you get `KeyValuePair`, which can't be iterated over, as error states.

So you need the value inside outer `foreach`, which would be the `Dictionary` you can iterate over, something like this:

```
foreach(var item in myDict)
{
    foreach(var rt in item.Value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, you could use `myDict.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray();` which would return array with all key and value pairs from all dictionaries, then you can iterate over all of them at once (without nesting loops).

Comment: but  wont be able to change values in internal dictionary with array

Comment: @murmansk You're right, then use loops like you did, with my suggested modification.